# Find Class which Call the Method

Tags: c#

Hi all
There is 2 Classes in project
First Class is a form.Like this.

```
  public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

//And Another Class Like this

```
public class Sample
{
public void MyMethod()
{
//My Codes
}
}
```

Now I want to learn that 
When I call the `MyMethod` in Form3 or another class I want learn which class called `MyMethod`?
Thanks.

Comment: At Runtime? or is thif for debugging

Comment: What do you mean "I want learn which class called myMethod?" ? For what reason ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108584/how-to-get-invoker-class-of-this-method)

Comment: I will use some information about class is called the method.Like
When Form3 class call the method i will use it a variable in MyMethod
MyMEthod()
{
(Form) CalledForm=...
CalledForm.Title="Sample"
}

Comment: Slightly similar thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178249/how-can-i-know-which-method-call-my-method

Comment: If you just need "some information" on who called the method, why not use a parameter to pass it?

Answer (score 3):

At runtime you can check the method name and the declaring type using following code.

```
 StackTrace trace=new StackTrace();
            StackFrame[] stackFrames = trace.GetFrames();
            foreach (var stackFrame in stackFrames)
            {
                string methodName= stackFrame.GetMethod().Name;
                string declearingClass=stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;

            }
```

you can skip the first frame to know exactly where your function called from

```
StackFrame[] stackFrames = trace.GetFrames().Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: But it's dangerous. See John Skeet's answer and user comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108584/how-to-get-invoker-class-of-this-method).

Answer (score 1):

accept a type object as one of the argument.

```
public class Sample
{
    public void MyMethod(Type CallerType)
    {
        //My Codes 
    } 
}
```

when you are calling that method call

```
SampleObj.MyMethod(this.gettype());
```

Comment: this is true but Can I make it unleess send parametr?

Comment: If you can tell your exact senario we can try some work arounds. 
If you want to do without passing a parameter, you can try Lnt3's answer

Answer (score 0):

1) Put a breakpoint in MyMethod()

2) Run your application

3) Wait until that breakpoint hits

4) Look at the stacktrace

Or:

1) Throw and catch an exception in MyMethod

2) Print the exceptions stacktrace

Comment: I will use some information about class is called the method.Like
When Form3 class call the method i will use it a variable in MyMethod
MyMEthod()
{
(Form) CalledForm=...
CalledForm.Title="Sample"
}

Comment: All I can say is, add a `Type` argument as @Chilaka said. That is the safest route out there.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, right-click on `MyMethod` -> Find all references.

Or alternatively, CTRL-K, R with the cursor on the method.