# how do we know which method (java.class) has called the current one

Tags: java, stack-trace

Example: If I have two classes: **A** and **B**. both class can call a method in **C** (example: the `init()` method)

From **C**, how do we know where the call is from (from Class **A** or Class **B**) ?

Comment: You can look at the stack trace but this is rarely a good idea (and its relatively slow)  You should instead pass to C all the important information. BTW You can pass a class as an argument e.g. `init(A.class);`

Comment: Technically it might be interesting, but in general code should not depend on the caller, it should depend on its parameters

Comment: can you give me an exemple ? thank you

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178249/how-can-i-know-which-method-call-my-method?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I find the caller of a method using stacktrace or reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421280/in-java-how-do-i-find-the-caller-of-a-method-using-stacktrace-or-reflection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it right, you should provide C's method with that information, for example via an enum or class parameter:

```
public void init(Object otherArg, Class<?> caller) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
public void init(Object otherArg, CallerEnum caller) {
    ...
}
```

But if you don't care, there is another way using the stack trace. Have a look at [Get current stack trace in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1069066/1374678) and use the second [StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) from the top of the stack to get the method that called the current one.

Answer (score 3):

This may be useful:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

- you can use this to get the stack trace of the current thread in a `StackTraceElement` array where the first element of the array is the most recent method invocation sequence on the stack
- provided the returned array is of non-zero length. 
  `StackTraceElement` has methods like `getClassName`, `getMethodName`, etc., which one can use to find the caller class name or method name.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from somewhere of the web...

```
private static final int CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX;

static {
    // Finds out the index of "this code" in the returned stack trace - funny but it differs in JDK 1.5 and 1.6
    int i = 0;
    for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
        i++;
        if (ste.getClassName().equals(MyClass.class.getName())) {
            break;
        }
    }
    CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX = i;
}

public static String getCurrentMethodName() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX].getMethodName();
}
public static String getCallerMethodName() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX+1].getMethodName();
}
```

Comment: I suspect the different depth depends on the number of call levels inside the getStackTrace which is called before the snapshot is taken. It could differ between vendors as well.

Comment: Executed on class X.foo - will return "foo", the static block is to prevent the problem you referred.

Comment: I was trying to explain why the static block was needed as you had the comment `funny but it differs in JDK 1.5 and 1.6`

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution (for me :D )

```
public <T> void init(Class<T> clazz) {
     if (!clazz.getSimpleName().equals("MyClassName")) {
          // do something
     }else{
          // do something
     }
}
```